# How to set a template color to a canvas of a kivy UI?

Tags: python, canvas, colors, kivy

Hej

I like to define a template for a color used to draw backgrounds of several GUI groups.

My kivy kv code looks like this:

```
<BGRcolor@Color>:
    rgb: 0.176, 0.176, 0.176

<myParamBox@BoxLayout>:
    canvas:
        BGRcolor:

        Rectangle:
            pos: root.pos
            size: root.size
        Color:
            rgb: 0.3, 0.3, 0.3
        Line:
            points: root.pos[0],root.pos[1], root.pos[0] + root.size[0],root.pos[1], root.pos[0] + root.size[0],root.pos[1] + root.size[1], root.pos[0] ,root.pos[1] + root.size[1], root.pos[0],root.pos[1]
    padding: 2
```

The setting of the Color for the canvas operation does not work. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Color is not a Widget, so you can't construct it like this. Actually there isn't really a syntax to make this directly more concise, but you could e.g. make all the widgets you want to have this color inherit from another Widget that has the Color rule.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution:

```
class myApp(kivy.app.App):

    BGcolor = (0.176, 0.176, 0.176, 1.0)

kivy.lang.Builder.load_string('''
<myParamBox@BoxLayout>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: app.BGcolor
        Rectangle:
            pos: root.pos
            size: root.size
        Color:
            rgb: 0.3, 0.3, 0.3
        Line:
            points: root.pos[0],root.pos[1], root.pos[0] + root.size[0],root.pos[1], root.pos[0] + root.size[0],root.pos[1] + root.size[1], root.pos[0] ,root.pos[1] + root.size[1], root.pos[0],root.pos[1]
    padding: 2
''')
```

define the color touple at the app instance and refer in the template to it.